# Re-indexing and Defragging in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

The whole concept of not re-indexing a database is new to me. Does MySQL keep its indexes upto date automatically?

I also came across the command **OPTIMIZE TABLE** in MySQL. Is this the same as re-indexing or does this accomplish something else?